How to keep a GitHub actions self hosted runner on ubuntu VM up and running always?
I have a self hosted runner on ubuntu vm. I have triggered the run.sh script with root as below:
RUNNER_ALLOW_RUNASROOT=1 ./run.sh &
now as soon as the vm gets disconnected the runner stops.What is the best practice to run a  self hosted runner on a vm and keep it up and running.
I have triggered the run.sh script with root as below:
RUNNER_ALLOW_RUNASROOT=1 ./run.sh &

Use nohup:
RUNNER_ALLOW_RUNASROOT=1 nohup ./run.sh &

